# How to overwrite file without deleting existing file?

Tags: bash

I have a node_exporter web server running which serves files from a directory. These files have host metrics at a particular point-in-time. I have a daemon running that scrapes metrics from other exporters every 15 seconds and writes to this directory. When it writes files, I think it removes the existing file and writes a new file. Because of this, once in a while, for a split second node_exporter serves no metrics from an exporter. How do I make sure the previous metrics exist until the new metrics are written and there's no empty/duplicate metrics?

Comment: Added duplicates describing how to do atomic updates both from node and from native bash, since the question doesn't include explicit code to be unambiguous.

Comment: So in bash there's no way to fix this? I don't see a solution in the duplicate you added for bash. Only says its not atomic

Comment: Renames within a single filesystem *are* atomic. I believe that's covered in the dupes -- I'll check, and if not, add more.

Comment: Ahh -- the node.js duplicate covers the create-and-rename pattern, the bash one didn't. Added an additional bash duplicate covering that ground.

Comment: To speak to the mechanism -- `foo > bar` opens the file `bar` with `O_TRUNC` *before* the command `foo` is even started, so it can connect `foo`'s stdout (FD 1) to that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. write to a temporary file in the same directory
2. when done, rename the temporary file to the result file

   ```
   mv tempfile outputfile
   ```

Comment: The question was tagged with "bash". If renamed from Node, Node should have the same directory and file access permissions. This might be somewhat less secure if Node is also a webserver.

Comment: so move command is atomic but redirection isn't?

Comment: yeah looks like its atomic. thanks!

Comment: redirection is not atomic. mv is 'mostly' atomic, see discussions about atomicity mv on stackoverflow